# Use Paypal Pro Directpayment in php

Tags: php

I am testing paypal sandbox with curl but every thime it is giving me login page of sandbox.What is wrong in it ?  I want to use paypal pro from my website. I dont want to go
on paypal site. All the payment must me done on website.

```
function PPHttpPost($methodName_, $nvpStr_){ 
                global $environment;
                // Set up your API credentials, PayPal end point, and API version.
                $API_UserName = urlencode('XXXXXXXXXXXXXX');
                $API_Password = urlencode('XXXXXXXX');
                $API_Signature = urlencode('XXXXXXXXXXXXX');

                $version = urlencode('51.0');

                // Set the curl parameters.
                $ch = curl_init("https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr");
                //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "");
                //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);

                // Turn off the server and peer verification (TrustManager Concept).
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
                //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, FALSE);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'cURL/PHP');
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);

                // Set the API operation, version, and API signature in the request.
                $nvpreq = "METHOD=$methodName_&VERSION=$version&PWD=$API_Password&USER=$API_UserName&SIGNATURE=$API_Signature$nvpStr_";

                // Set the request as a POST FIELD for curl.
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $nvpreq);

                // Get response from the server.
                $httpResponse = curl_exec($ch);
                   print_r($httpResponse); die;
                if(!$httpResponse) {
                    exit("$methodName_ failed: ".curl_error($ch).'('.curl_errno($ch).')');
                }

                // Extract the response details.
                $httpResponseAr = explode("&", $httpResponse);

                $httpParsedResponseAr = array();
                foreach ($httpResponseAr as $i => $value) {
                    $tmpAr = explode("=", $value);
                    if(sizeof($tmpAr) > 1) {
                        $httpParsedResponseAr[$tmpAr[0]] = $tmpAr[1];
                    }
                }

                if((0 == sizeof($httpParsedResponseAr)) || !array_key_exists('ACK', $httpParsedResponseAr)) {
                    //exit("Invalid HTTP Response for POST request($nvpreq) to $API_Endpoint.");
                }

                return $httpParsedResponseAr;
            }
```

Comment: There is nothing wrong with it... If Your environment is "sandbox" then You have to login to Sandbox to procceed with (sandbox) payment... User has to login to PayPal to be able to approve the payment...And PayPal won't let You to collect users credentials for PayPal accounts on Your website, therefore user has to be redirected to PayPal to log in...

Comment: never share you api keys publicly.

Comment: Thanks but those were of my sandbox account.

Comment: @shadyyx comment is absolutely correct. Login to your paypal Sandbox account, then login to seller account that may be you have created already and ultimately do the checkout. Use the same browser for the above mentioned process i.e. if you are using Firefox then open sanbox account of paypal and your website on the same browser.I hope this will help :)